# What Is The Heat Of Combustion Of Diesel And How Do I Find It?

Tags: organic-chemistry, combustion, fuel

I need help in finding the heat of combustion of diesel, no where online can i find it, and my chemistry teacher does not know how to find it....

Comment: For a rough start you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Table_of_energy_content and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_fuel#Fuel_value_and_price (about 45 MJ/kg) but the thermodynamics of combustion may make a complete answer more complicated than that